# Cordova CLI android path error

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-cli

I changed the directory structure E: to R:, but still in `build.xml` is picking the `E:\Adroid SDK\...` path, infact the `ANDROID_HOME` variable is correct `R:\Android SDK\...` but still.

This is the error I'm getting while running `cordova run android` command.

```
R:\Cordova\workshop>cordova run android
Running command: cmd "/s /c "R:\Cordova\workshop\platforms\android\cordova\run.b
at""
Buildfile: R:\Cordova\workshop\platforms\android\build.xml
BUILD FAILED
R:\Cordova\workshop\platforms\android\build.xml:90: Cannot find E:\Android SDK\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml imported from R:\Cordova\workshop\platforms\android\build.xml

Total time: 0 seconds

R:\Cordova\workshop\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                throw e;
                      ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,R:\Cordova\workshop\platforms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen 
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit
code 8
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

Any body have any idea why the old pah is still there and how to change it, it'll be helpfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sorted out by just replacing with only those `java` files, `www` and `plugins`folder which are different, but still using `Gradle` build.Trying to use `Ant` build. Currently I'm back on track, no issue with compiling.

I'm sure this will help you so that you can start development again.

But be careful while manipulating `java` files, by the way you get the errors you can be able to sort it, but still.

Answer (score 1):

The original path is stored in some files in the platforms/android folder. (seen it at least in fileSnapshots.bin in the .gradle folder) when you add the android platform to your project.

First thing you can try is to run platforms\android\cordova\clean.bat to see if it corrects your issue.

If it doesn't work I think the easiest would be to remove the android platform and re-add it. (be sure to save any files you may have modified in the platforms/android folder before you proceed!)

```
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android
```

(maybe add a version number with @versionnumber if you need to use a specific version or the android platform)

Comment: I'am trying to install ant not gradle, but every time i install `cordova platform add android` gradle is installed. This is apart from the question I asked. Can you tell why gradle is installed not able install ant build ?

Comment: Cordova switched from ant build to graddle some time ago (around 4.x I think). Your issue is not caused by graddle, you might have the same issue with ant because ant build also left hard coded path in files. If you don't want to use graddle but use ant, there's somewhere a SO question where someone indicated the command to force ant build.

Comment: I checked many file and change the path, but not getting he path which specifies the `E:\Android SDK\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml`. Do have any idea where i can get this.

Comment: In my case, the hard coded path is in platforms\android\.gradle\2.2.1\taskArtifacts\fileSnapshots.bin, but since it's a binary file I wouldn't recommend editing it. Do you still have the "Cannot find E:\Android SDK\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml" message after removing and re-adding the platform?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it several times. Actually I have the old code and what I do is jut copy the `platform` `plugins` and `www` direecories from the old project tring to run it, because I have changed some `src` codes, so don't want to mess with that.

Comment: If you have only android platform, completly delete the platforms folder (you may have a corrupted platforms.json file). About plugins, if they have from a older version of cordova, I would recommend also removing all plugins and re-installing them (and be carefull, the plugins ids have changed in cordova 5)